# Database: Many Records VS Many Columns for Count by Time

Tags: database, database-design

I making some summariable values like count, average per Time unit
It's some kind of Time series.

I'm already made "many records".
It was not satisfactory in terms of speed.

Unfortunately, the speed slows down as the number of records increases.

Some answers told the "many record" is better than "many columns"

Example:

- Summary for minute
- INSERT or update per 1 second
- for 1 year

"Many records" results in a dataset of 525600 records with 2 columns:

| time | count |
| --- | --- |
| y-m-d 01 | 60 |
| y-m-d 02 | 60 |
| ~ |  |
| y-m-d 23 | 60 |
| y-m-d 24 | 60 |

"Many columns" results in a dataset of 21600 records and 26 columns

| time | h_1 | h_2 | ~ | h_23 | h_24 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| y-m-d h | 60 | 60 | ~ | 60 | 60 |
| y-m-d h | 60 | 60 | ~ | 60 | 60 |

I felt merit the number of records.

Will "many columns" work better than "many records" for this case when looking at `SELECT` performance?

Comment: I don't understand the differences between the two designs, but my guess is that the "many rows" version would be the best design here.

Comment: Assuming you're using an actual timestamp and not a string representing a timestamp in the database, the many records approach should be better.  I wouldn't make the timestamp the primary key, but put a unique index on timestamp descending.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I made "many record" version already, I tried Timestamp as Integer and unique. and It has another Auto Increament PK.
Almost same with your discussin.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are referring to is the storage of time series data, therefore have a look at database products created exactly for this purpose. Here is for example a comprehensive Video of how [Influx](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2SUBRE6wGiA) works, one of the main players in the time series db market. They might give you the performance you need when aggregating values.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you recommend for it?

Comment: You could have a look at an [evaluation of different time series db] (https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S1877050919310439?token=32FC0D6682A44C19E5247D27A462C227677B666FBD514ED45585191EAAC485B833995E2A5C15D0B8DFBB8841ACC74982&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210929114253). Pick the one that matches your requirements best.